# IOS Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-reports

Good afternoon colleagues

Recently, I have been receiving reports through the organizer from users of the crash application.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010
VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476720
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Triggered by Thread:  0


Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d30f9c20 objc_msgSend + 32 (:-1)
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc192224 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 768 (UIViewController.m:3098)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc18fdf8 -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308 (UINavigationController.m:774)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d30f95d8 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196 (NSObject.mm:938)
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d30fcf80 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256 (NSObject.mm:1208)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc192340 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1052 (UIViewController.m:3128)
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc18fdf8 -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308 (UINavigationController.m:774)
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d30f95d8 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196 (NSObject.mm:938)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d30fcf80 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256 (NSObject.mm:1208)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d9e4e764 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 32 (NSObject.m:793)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d9e4c4b8 __CFRunLoopPerCalloutARPEnd + 48 (CFRunLoop.c:746)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d9e4c080 __CFRunLoopRun + 2076 (CFRunLoop.c:3149)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d9e50ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
13  GraphicsServices                0x0000000213152368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc32f3d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3745)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001dc32f034 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5335)
16  AppIOS                          0x000000010546defc main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:21)
17  dyld                            0x00000001f84b8960 start + 2528 (dyldMain.cpp:1170)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001120ac600   x1: 0x00000001d5cacf78   x2: 0x0000000112910400   x3: 0x000000016ae5a268
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000111f5d290   x6: 0x0000000000000020   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000280568de0   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x6ae10001120ac600  x11: 0x000000000000001f
   x12: 0x0000000000984000  x13: 0x0000000111f42fe0  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000235516f30  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000112910400
   x20: 0x00000001128096c8  x21: 0x0000000280568de0  x22: 0x0000000000000050  x23: 0x00000000000001b8
   x24: 0x000000022d863000  x25: 0x0000000100000002  x26: 0x0000000000000050  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000283eb1210   fp: 0x000000016ae5a3c0   lr: 0x00000001dc192224
    sp: 0x000000016ae5a1a0   pc: 0x00000001d30f9c20 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

I can't figure out why the crash is happening.
The rootViewController itself is initialized through the code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

//...//

 var window: UIWindow?

 func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
    createRootVC()
}

private func createRootVC() {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainView = Main_V2()
        let navigation = RootNavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigation
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

//..//

}
```

In Main_V2, this is a continuation of the Launch Screen, which has a network request and determines which screen will be next on the stack. After opening the next screen, Main_V2 is removed from the viewControllers stack of the root navigation controller.

The error is not reproduced by own efforts. Even with AddressSanitizer and ZombieObject scan enabled.

The application also has a timer restart when the application goes into the background. After 5 minutes, the screens restart:

```
 private func restartApp() {
        let mainView = Main_V2()
        let navigation = RootNavigationController(rootViewController: mainView)
        // Get current Window with RootViewController
        guard
            let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
            let rootVC = window.rootViewController
        else {
            createRootVC()
            return
        }
        // Change frame of current root frame
        navigation.view.frame = rootVC.view.frame
        navigation.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        // Clear All
        window.rootViewController = nil
        
        // Animate transition new rootViewController
        UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
            window.rootViewController = navigation
        }
    }
```

But judging by the report, it's not about the restart, but the first cold start of the application.

There are no dsym files for UIKit in the downloaded Debug Symbols, so it is not possible to check the cause through the %atos -arch arm64 -o command

I would be very grateful if you could tell me what the reason may be or how to investigate this report.

Comment: It looks like you are holding a reference to a deallocated or deallocating object. Start with the Zombies instrument.

Comment: Zombie enabled, but still can't identify the problem

Comment: Try removing `window.rootViewController = nil`. Also as per your description, you reset the app after 5s of it being in background. You cannot run animations in background hence your call to UIView.transition(with, duration) makes no sense to me, just swap root VC.

Comment: Previously, there was no window.rootViewController = nil, but crashes still came. Restarting the application is different. When the application goes into the background, the time is recorded. When the application is deployed again and if the difference between the recorded time and the current one is 5 minutes or more, the restartApp() function is called